# Audio delays progressively when recording with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, screencast, desktop-recording, video-recording, audio-sync

I am trying to record screencasts in Ubuntu 12.04; I have a working command; the audio sounds great and the video looks great.

I have one issue though, the audio delays as the video goes on. At the begining of the video the audio and video are synced together but as the video progresses the audio delay is bigger. I tried to record the video and audio streams separately, and it seems at the end that the audio is 1 second longer than the video and that is for roughly 6 minutes of recording. If I record for 10 minutes the delay is of roughly 2 seconds.

I have no possibility of fixing that issue in editing, simply because it is not a matter of consistent delay, but a progressively increasing one.

I tried other screencasting apps, probably all of them and they either simply don't work or they crash my computer (kazam). 
Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: Please at least show your ffmpeg command and the complete console output.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

Your computer is probably underpowered for the codecs your are trying to use.

my solution was to choose a different codec https://askubuntu.com/a/154275/56440